# What is the difference between gradle install and gradle publishToMavenLocal?

Tags: gradle

In gradle, the `install` task is introduced by the `maven` plugin.

The `publishToMavenLocal` task is introduced by the `maven-publish` plugin.

The documentation of both tasks says they install/publish the module/artifacts to the local maven cache (`.m2` directory).

If I need to publish a local project to my local maven cache, so that another local project can depend on it, which of the two tasks should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, these two accomplish the same thing.

That said, I recommend using the `maven-publish` plugin because:

- It's newer and has a nicer publishing DSL, see the [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) page for more details
- It doesn't explicitly depend on the `java` plugin, which is useful if you ever build non-Java projects

You can always write: `task install(dependsOn: 'publishToMavenLocal')` if you like the task name `install`.

Comment: Thanks for the task hint :)